# is there any Hangfire job to run on all servers?

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc, hangfire

In my problem:

1- Have a web farm with about 10 servers

2- Have some global settings that are stored in database

3- These settings are used at a high rate in controllers (about 10 times in each request)

4- If some settings have been changed in database, all the servers in web farm should update their settings.

So referring to database in each request seems to not be a good solution. 
As result I prefer to:

1- store these settings in `static` properties

2- have a recurring job in each server to check database for changes in every second and then update these `static` properties.

But it seems `Hangfire` jobs only run in one server. Is there any way to force it to call the job on all server instances?

Answer (score 2):

I can get hangfire recurring job to run on all server with the following code block

string jobName = string.Format("{0}-CacheDepdencyCheck", Environment.MachineName);

```
                RecurringJob.AddOrUpdate(jobName, () => CacheHelper.ClearExpirationCaches(), String.Format("*/{0} * * * *", frequency));
```

Comment: Thanks but it will fails in web garden mode (when your app distributed across processors of one machine).

Answer (score 2):

I think it does not support this feature at API level yet. But you could get a work around by using the Job Queue feature.

For example, if you have 10 servers, you can configure them with some custom queue name besides the default one, and specify them in the server starting option, refer to this [link](http://docs.hangfire.io/en/latest/background-processing/configuring-queues.html)

In you client code, you have to queue the job manually:

`var queueState = new EnqueuedState("custom_queue_name_*") // * = from 1 to 10`

And use hangfire client to enqueue the job with this queue state.

For 10 instances server group, enqueue the job ten times with custom queue name, you will get them run everywhere.

Be sure to make your actual execution logic reentrant.

Comment: The problem with this approach is we should save the number in somewhere (for example in web.config). This approach will fail when you have web garden(no web farm). I mean when you force IIS to use more than one processor instead of clustering your web application across physical servers

Answer (score 1):

As one of `Hangfire` developers mentioned [here](https://discuss.hangfire.io/t/one-queue-for-the-whole-farm-and-one-queue-by-server/490/2), this feature is not available with `Hangfire` currently and he suggests to use `System.Threading.Timer`